# Finding the distance under a position-time graph

Tags: kinematics, integration, calculus

I have to find the distance travelled by a particle between t=0 and t=4 secs for x(t)= 4t^2 - 2t^3. I tried differentiating the equation to find v(t) then integrating it within t=0 and t=4, but that got me the displacement. I'm pretty stumped. The maxima is at t=4/3, which is when the velocity turns negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand what is actually happening - the body first moves with **some speed in positive x-axis direction, and at time = 4/3 the velocity becomes 0 and the body reverses its direction of motion**. The thing which you are calling maxima, it is the point where the rate of change of function with respect to time is 0 - which means velocity is 0. **Before and after that critical point, the sign of derivative is different** - which is the direction of velocity is different.

To find the distance basically **decompose the motion** into two parts - one, where it is moving towards positive x axis and second, when its moving towards negative x axis. **Integrate the function breaking the motion into these two parts**. Once integrate it between t=0 to t=4/3, second integrate it between t=4/3 to t=4, the answers you get in both - add the **absolute value** of them to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The distance travelled is just x(4s)-x(0s) so it is just x(4s), since usually distance means the absolute value, you have to take |x(4s)| Since there are no units, one does not know if its miles or m or???

Comment: ah, sorry. It's metres. The issue is that taking the value of |x(4s)| does not give me the right answer, as it gives the position of the particle at t=4s, which is not the same as the distance travelled by the particle in 4 seconds.